# C# SkipWhile(Item => Item == null) still returns null items

Tags: c#, list, foreach, null, skip

I have a list of items:

```
List<Item> ItemList = new List<Item>;
```

Sometimes the list is only partially full or certain indices are not occupied and therefore when I iterate through the list using a foreach, it gives an error because the item is null. I want to reduce that list to those items which actually have a value. This is what I'm trying:

```
var FullItems = ItemList.SkipWhile(Item => Item == null).ToList();
```

But when I check the FullItems list, it still contains the items from ItemList that are null, so I'm just getting back the entire list that I started with.

Help?

Comment: _"it still contains the items from ItemList that are null"_ - but not the ones at the beginning. Are you looking for `.Where(i => i != null)`?

Comment: `SkipWhile` returns everything including and after the first non-null element. Use `ItemList.Where`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SkipWhile(i => i == null)` will *skip until the first non-null item*. Items *after* that first one which are null are still ignored.

Use `Where(i => i != null)` to select all items that are not null.

Comment: Thank you! Only working until the first non-null item is not exactly what I expected.

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for here is:

```
var FullItems = ItemList.Where(Item => Item != null).ToList();
```

As per the [docs on `SkipWhile()`:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549075(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Bypasses elements in a sequence as long as a specified condition is true and then **returns the remaining elements**.

This is not the behavior you are looking for (I have **bolded the actual behavior that you don't seem to expect/desire**).

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem fully. You are correct in that I was supposed to user Where(), but returning the remaining items is exactly the behaviour I needed. The problem is that SkipWhile(i = null) only works up until the first non-null item. If the first few items in my list were null then the code I wrote would work fine.